# Is it possible to query only some fields in a DataStore query like you can with a graphql query?

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify, datastore

With the aws-amplify JS library, you can execute a graphql query that brings back a list of objects and only a subset of their fields.

[image]

Can I do the same with an AWS Amplify DataStore query? Or do DataStore queries need to return all fields of the objects?

```
  this.users = await DataStore.query(User, Predicates.ALL)
```

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?

Comment: unfortunately not yet